# Is the IBM MQ MacOS toolkit supported on Catalina?

Tags: macos, ibm-mq, macos-catalina

I had the [IBM MQ MacOS toolkit](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2019/02/05/ibm-mq-macos-toolkit-for-developers/) working well on MacOS High Sierra, but I have now upgraded to Catalina and it's not working.

In this new release Gatekeeper checks binaries started from Terminal.app, so when I run (say) `runmqsc`, I get an annoying pop up saying

```
"runmqsc" cannot be opened because the
developer cannot be verified.
macOS cannot verify that this app is free 
from malware.

Chrome downloaded this file on 15 September 2019 
from www14.software.ibm.com.

                    [Move to Bin] [Cancel]
```

I've tried some of the solutions for this general problem, (for example [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so)), but it would be better if IBM could supply properly signed software so that it worked without these work-arounds.

Does anyone know if there is a version of the IBM MQ MacOS toolkit that works properly on MacOS Catalina?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for raising this, we are aware of the problem and we are looking into it. The problem applies to all non-notarised executables on Catalina.

Starting with Catalina, Apple has tightened what apps are allowed to run on a Mac. All applications and dlls must be signed and notarised.

It is possible to get the client to run on Catalina, but involves a long winded process of removing each executable / dll from quarantine when it is required to be run.

If you take a look at System Preferences -> Security & Privacy on the General tab, you will see a notification of the last app / dll that was not allowed to run. You can remove it from quarantine from that panel, but need to repeat the process for each exe and dll.

> Update as of Dec 2020
>
> > The IBM MQ macOS Toolkit is made available as a signed package (.pkg) https://ibm.biz/mqdevmacclient

> > This means that you can download and double click to install. The installer by default installs in `/opt/mqm` , but you can move it after the install.
> >
> > On my Mac I have `/opt/mqm` as a symbolic link to a directory in my home location `~`
> >
> > Remember to add `/opt/mqm/bin` and `/opt/mqm/samp/bin` to the path
> > and `/opt/mqm/lib64` to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: OK thanks, can you share an ETA of a notarized version then?  Perhaps I should wait for that before accepting this answer?

Comment: @Thruston perhaps you should accept it now?